# html select does not enable in the UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have this html code

```
<td width="300px">
     <select id="Drpdwn_application2" 
             name="Drpdwn_application2" 
             ClientIDMode="static" 
             class="multiselect" 
             runat="server">
      </select>
</td>
```

I was wondering why this javascript is not working:

```
<script>
    // other codes
    document.getElementById("Drpdwn_application2").disabled = false;
</script>
```

as an alternative, I also tried this but still aint working,

```
var cbox = $("#Drpdwn_application2");
cbox.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
cbox.prop('disabled', false);
```

some other declaration:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/capability.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="style/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

EDIT:

when i tried to check the value of the property `disabled` using `alert`, it displays the correct value, eg

```
alert(document.getElementById("Drpdwn_application2").disabled);
// return true/false
// which i think is working
// but the control in the UI is not updating
```

Comment: In your alternative, did you mean to refer to #Drpdwn_application3, instead of #Drpdwn_application2?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd sorry, it was a typo :) updated the question.

Comment: Are you trying to make it disabled or enabled?

Comment: That is not valid HTML; a td element cannot exist on it's own, it always has to have it's ancestors all the way to `table`. Expect weird behavior otherwise.

Comment: @user3558931 It's inside `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Here,

This is to ENABLE the select

```
 $('#Drpdwn_application2').prop('disabled', false);
```

and to disable the select, use

```
 $('#Drpdwn_application2').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> Javascript

```
<script>
function disable() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled=true;
}
function enable() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled=false;
}
</script>
```

> Your HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="disable()" value="Disable list">
<input type="button" onclick="enable()" value="Enable list">
```

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_select_disabled)